# Include works in other files but not on this one

Tags: c

This is driving me crazy.

```
in file second.c : implicit declaration of function ‘be64toh’.

in file first.c : be64toh works perfectly.
```

I even included every include of the first.h into second.h, nothing.

I even included first.h in second.c, nothing

Only way for it to compile is to add :

```
#define _DEFAULT_SOURCE

//warning: "_DEFAULT_SOURCE" redefined
```

Is there something I don't understand about includes ?

I have a lot of files, and some of them are interconnected with includes, so I can't post all files.

Comment: *"I even included every include of the first.h into second.h"* nice, but what about the .c files. It's *their* include hierarchies that ultimately matter. Normally this kind of thing happens when someone mistakenly uses the *same* include guard in multiple headers, or just plain forgets to include a specific header. You can utilizes a preprocessor intermediate output from your compiler chain and see if what you expect is present is where it is supposed to be. Check your compiler tools for how to use their preprocessor feature(s).

Comment: If you read the [be64toh manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/be64toh) you'll see it requires the `_BSD_SOURCE` feature macro to be defined. I'm not sure what `_DEFAULT_SOURCE` is in your code but I'm guessing it's turning on `_BSD_SOURCE`.

Comment: I assume that making a [mre] to demonstrate the problem is out of the question. I totally understand that extracting one from a big library is near impossible. However, you might try to make one from scratch which provokes the same error. It might give you insights.